# Angular Kendo Grid throw NullInjectorError: No provider for ColumnResizingService

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

My angular component throw the following error.  While in the root module, this error is not thrown but when I move the component to a new sub module (ContractModule), this exception is thrown and a few others things seem to be broken. I do import the GridModule at the module level.

vendor.js:280722 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ContractModule)[ColumnResizingService -> ColumnResizingService -> ColumnResizingService -> ColumnResizingService]:

[thrown Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e61kh.png)

Comment: Did you update path in AppModule when you move your component.

Comment: Yes. I did update. I did it for the component and also I do not have ColumnResizingService  anywhere in my code and this service came along with Kendo grid I think.